# Rails Parellel gem: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rubygems, mysql2

I have the following code in my rails app

```
results = Parallel.map(user_ids, :in_processes => 4) do |user_id|
  <some calculations>
  [user_id, result]
end
```

This works properly in development environment. But when I try to test the method which contains this code, test fails with `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away`

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Check mysql log and attach excerpt